# What is scheduler delay in spark UI's event timeline

Tags: apache-spark

I am using YARN environment to run spark programs,
with option `--master yarn-cluster`.

When I open a spark application's application master, I saw a lot of `Scheduler Delay` in a stage. Some of them are even more than 10 minutes. I wonder what are they and why it takes so long?

Update:
Usually operations like aggregateByKey take much more time (i.e. scheduler delay) before executors really start doing tasks. Why is it?

Answer (score 17):

Open the "Show Additional Metrics" (click the right-pointing triangle so it points down) and mouse over the check box for "Scheduler Delay". It shows this tooltip:

> Scheduler delay includes time to ship the task from the scheduler to the executor, and time to send the task result from the executor to
>   the scheduler. If scheduler delay is large, consider decreasing the
>   size of tasks or decreasing the size of task results.

The scheduler is part of the master that divides the job into stages of tasks and works with the underlying cluster infrastructure to distribute them around the cluster.

Comment: Hard to know without more information about your job. Do you have a lot more tasks than cores? How big is the stuff returned by @aggregateByKey@?

Comment: The number of tasks is very large, e.g. 80000.  When I apply operation like map, there is almost no scheduler delay. However operation like aggregateByKey or join,  scheduler delay becomes more than 4 minutes.

Comment: If you have less than 80K cores, many tasks will wait for an open slot. Furthermore, operations like `join` and `aggregate*`, as well as `fold*`, `reduce*`, and `groupBy` require data shuffled to them by upstream tasks, so they have to wait until those are done (although they can start pulling some data over as its available).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at TaskSetManager's class comment:

..Schedules the tasks within a single TaskSet in the TaskSchedulerImpl. This class keeps track of each task, retries tasks if they fail (up to a limited number of times), and handles l**ocality-aware scheduling** for this TaskSet via delay scheduling...

I assume it is the result of the following paper, on which Matei Zaharia was working (co-founder and Chief Technologist of Databricks which develop Spark) ,too: https://cs.stanford.edu/~matei/

Thus, Spark is checking the partition's locality of a pending task. If the locality-level is low (e.g. not on local jvm) the task gets not directly killed or ignored, Instead it gets a launch delay, which is fair.