# Spark processing time increases for each sequential task

Tags: scala, apache-spark, reduce

I'm new to spark and scala, and have just written some Scala code that groups data in my RDD by four keys and sums a fifth. My intention is to replicate this SQL statement:

```
SELECT iso, id1, id2, convert(thresh), sum(area::double)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY iso, id1, id2, convert(thresh)
```

My scala code is as follows, where `finalRDD` is an RDD and `convert` is a simple function to bin integers from 1-100:

```
  finalRDD
    .map({case Array(lon, lat, thresh, area, iso, id1, id2) => ((iso, id1, id2, convert(thresh)), (area.toDouble)) })
    .reduceByKey(_+_)
    .map({ case (key, value) => Array(key._1, key._2, key._3, key._4, value)
    .mkString(",")})
    .saveAsTextFile(conf.get("output.path"))
```

When I run this process on a large dataset (3.5 TB, parallelized into 113,000 tasks), the first 30,000 tasks finish each within a second or two. An hour later, however, each task takes 15 - 20 minutes to complete.

I'm running this in Spark 2.0.0 on AWS EMR with 13 d2.8xlarge machines (244 GB memory and 36 cores each). I run the .jar using:

`spark-submit --master yarn --executor-memory 20g --jars my_jar.jar`

The Spark UI reports that all tasks are finishing relatively quickly (3 - 5 seconds), but it does show increasing amounts of scheduler delay time, the largest of these is 23 minutes.

Is this the likely cause of the increasing time to completion for each task? And is there a way to better structure my code (or config) to avoid this? Is reduceByKey to blame?

--- UPDATE ---

I've updated my code to utilize Spark Dataframes, letting Spark determine the best execution plan to group and sum my data. The updated code is as follows:

```
case class TableRow(iso: String, id1: String, id2: String, thresh: Long, area: Double)

finalRDD
      .map({case Array(lon, lat, thresh, area, iso, id1, id2) => (TableRow(iso, id1, id2, matchTest(thresh), area.toDouble)) })
      .toDF()
      .groupBy("iso", "id1", "id2", "thresh").agg(sum("area").alias("area_out"))
      .write
      .format("csv")
      .save(conf.get("output.path"))
```

When running this updated code, I did not experience the scheduler delay error, which was great. I did encounter errors connecting to executors and having them time out. Having already spent a fair amount of time and money on this d2.8xlarge cluster, I ended up splitting my job into 14 separate jobs, which all completed successfully.

Comment: Initial assumption is that perhaps you are generating and eliminating a lot of objects which requires a lot of garbage collection. This could be confirmed if the `GC Time` column in the spark interface is getting larger for each new task. Maybe the executors for this job just need more memory?

Comment: @TravisHegner Thanks for your comment-- much appreciated. How much `--executor-memory` would you recommend trying?

Comment: Unfortunately I wouldn't know off hand. But as I contemplate a bit more, it may be related to the fact that as your `reduceByKey()` runs, each partition causes the required amount of shuffle data to grow. So it's more likely related to that. I haven't run spark on yarn for some time, but perhaps the external shuffle service could make that shuffle more efficient? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#configuration-and-setup

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578278/what-is-scheduler-delay-in-spark-uis-event-timeline, and this is a good explanation of what happens to the data in your `reduceByKey()`: https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html

Comment: @TravisHegner Thanks for looking into this. I'll try using the external shuffle service on Monday. Would it also help to have fewer executors with more memory to reduce shuffle?

Comment: I'm not sure if the shuffle service will help, just kind of grasping at straws. Actually fewer partitions would probably work the best to reduce shuffle. That may also require more memory per executor.

Comment: Are you configuring `spark.executor.cores` to anything besides default? In my experience on yarn, you want to try to optimize the number of executors to as few as possible per host, to reduce executor overhead. You do this by specifying the `spark.executor.cores` parameter. This allows spark to more efficiently utilize memory between tasks, while still running the same number of simultaneous tasks. I would try it with 35 cores and 70GB *per executor*, and then tweak the number of partitions until you get it running at about 1-5 minutes per task on average. If you get OOMs, add more RAM.

Comment: @TravisHegner I'll give it a try. I'm currently not setting `spark.executor.cores` to anything. Are you suggesting I run `spark-submit` with `--executor-cores 35` and `--executor-memory 70g`? Regarding partitions, it seems like I have more partitions than is optimal. Should I use `coalesce` to decrease that number, or is that just extra work given that I'm going to `reduceByKey` immediately after?

Comment: Yes, that is correct on the parameters. The default # of cores on yarn is 1, so you are creating 35-36 executors per host right now. Regarding the `coalesce`, I would first try to determine what is causing that many partitions, and see if it's possible to reduce that in a previous step. If not, then a `coalesce` may work but will cause it's own partial (pre-aggregate) shuffle aside from the `reduceByKey`. You'll just have to experiment to see which way runs more optimally.

Comment: If other yarn apps are utilizing the cluster, you may have to reduce your core count, or some hosts may never start an executor. IMO, your goal should be to get as many cores per executor as possible, while still getting an executor to launch on every host. A good starting point for memory is usually 1-2GB per core, then adjust as needed.

Comment: Got it, I'll give it a try with those parameters. I believe the 113,000 partitions are the default from when I load my text file into an RDD. I don't set this value, and based on my reading of the spark docs, I can't set this value to something lower than the default. I'll try setting the number of cores first, then experiment with `coalesce`. Thank you!

Comment: If you are reading from HDFS, it will create a task per block (or per file if the files are smaller than a block). Naturally, the optimal file size is roughly the HDFS block size. If this data set is immutable, and you plan to run many more calculations, it may be worth it to write a job that concatenates small files into fewer larger ones (if the data allows for this, of course). If this is a continuous stream of small record type data, then you probably want to re-think your import/storage strategy. Hbase is really good for storing lots of small records on HDFS optimally.

Comment: The dataset is 15,000 text files, ranging in size from 10 lines to 0.5 GB. The data is immutable, but I'm only using it for this task, then will delete it. Do you think reorganizing it might help?

Comment: In that case, it wouldn't help any more than just doing a `coalesce` right before your `reduceByKey`. Reorganizing would essentially just be a `coalesce` saved to disk anyway.

Comment: @TravisHegner Thanks again for all of your help. I tried setting `--executor-memory` to 70gb, but still encountered the issue. Per the advice of a coworker, I updated my code (above) to use Spark Dataframes. This led to other problems, but I did eventually complete the task. Thanks for helping me walk through it!