# PySpark groupby strange behaviour

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata, data-processing

I am querying a large (2 trillion records) parquet file using PySpark, partitioned by two columns, **month** and **day** .

If I run a simple query as:

```
SELECT month, day, count(*) FROM mytable 
WHERE month >= 201801 and month< 202301  -- two years data
GROUP BY month, day 
ORDER BY month, day
```

the query is executed in 5 min or less. Super good performance!

If, I remove the where condition, it will bring whole data lake information (4 years). This query will take 1.5 hours to execute.

This behaviour is far from normal. I guess might be related to the large amount of data being queried in the workers node, leading to GC or shuffle, but is just a guess

**How can I debug above situation?**

My understanding is that Spark should be clever enough to calculate per partion (since is a distributed environment), and take around 5 * 2 (double years), not so much big different

**Edit1: Adding information from SparkUI**

I will put the screenshots of the two runs, 4 years data, 1.7 hours, and 3 years data, 7.5 min. First, always the 4 years data

**General overview**
[image]

[image]

**Job Page**

[image]
[image]

**Stage 1 - Heavy stage**

[image]

[image]

**Stage 2**

[image]

[image]

**SQL**

[image]

[image]

**Edit 2 - New findings - Scheduler delay**
In the heavy task, I have found out an scheduler delay
[image]

If this is the case, what is the approach?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: OR, your data may be skewed

Comment: side note - this is where, i feel, ORC comes in handy as it stores partition level stats within the partition, and spark (or hive) does not need to read the whole partition to get basic stats.

Comment: Try to find out using Spark UI if there any tasks that process significantly larger amount of data than most of the other tasks. Please see [Unpacking the Spark Web UI](https://ianwhitestone.work/spark-web-ui/) article by Ian Whitestone.

Comment: @samkart Data is the same day data copied for 4 years.

Comment: re: high scheduler delay, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31578278/8279585). also, is the data stored across multiple files or just 1 50GB parquet file?

Answer (score 1):

I have found what was the problem.

> By increasing the memory and cores (not really important) of the
> Driver, the problem was solved.

**How to reach this conclusion?**

First, I knew my data was not very skewed (as pointed by @samkart and @Leonid Vasilev). but, I checked again.

Second, all metrics were very similar to each other, without great number differences, soooo, it had to be something.

Third and lastly, I open the Stage Event line, and found a very interesting issue, see **edit 2**.

After further investigating why my scheduler was so delayed, I really didn't find the real reason, but this sentence gave me the hint. The problem was in the **driver**

> Scheduler delay (blue) is the time spent waiting. There is something
> that the executors are waiting for - often this is waiting for the
> driver that controls and coordinates the jobs.

source: [enter link description here](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2018/03/14/apache-spark-question-everything.html)

In that post, the author also mention something very important that I wish to add

> See all that red and blue? This is a sure sign that something is up.
> What we really want to see is lots of green - the proportion of time
> spent doing work - I mean real work - the part where Spark does the
> number crunching.

**TDLR:**

**Biggest problem came from Scheduler delay, very related to driver. Increasing the Memory (and vCPUs), solved the issue.**

Comment: Out of interest, what was the initial driver memory and what did you change it to? It often feels wasteful to over-resource the driver, but issues like this highlight that trying to optimize too heavily seem to bite.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst Initial driver was 2 vCPU - 7 GB RAM, increased to 4 vCPU 15 GB RAM.